# Lua on Cherokee

Tags: php, lua, webserver, cherokee

Has anyone configured or tried to configure CGILua on Cherokee Web Server.

What i really wanted was to process lua pages (.lp) together with PHP on Cherokee (PHP for writing on DB and handling user data and Lua for reading from the data base and handling other pages).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers_scgi.html ?
If you have good socket support in Lua (with some module) and have good network programing knowledge you could make something like SCGI server.
I'm developing such thing and currently this works really good (but I'm using nginx).

[SCGI protocol](http://www.python.ca/scgi/protocol.txt)

[SCGI WIKI article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Common_Gateway_Interface)

Comment: Great! (but i don't know much about network programming and working with servers, yet. yet.), actually i was looking at getting CGILua running on NGINX. I'm developing a web app in PHP at the moment but once i finish that i'll return looking at the Lua+NGINX situation. 

http://blog.marmottus.net/2012/03/25/nginx-and-lua/